# jQuery animation with borders IE8 (probably not only) issue

Tags: jquery, animation, border

I have issue
$('#myimg').animate({
  border: '10px solid #ffffff'
},'fast',function(){
  alert('callback');
});
Working with: FF 3.6.3, Chrome 5.0.375.55, Opera 10.53
Not working with: 8.0.7600.16385
Issue, no callback ;)
With animation for example "width", callback works also in IE, bug is with border.

Comment: IE doesn't seem to like the border shorthand. Particularly the color part. Interesting why that is.

Answer (score 1):

leave the color and variant in the css if you don't want to change them and just animate the border width:

```
$('#myimg').animate({ 'border-width': 10 }, 'fast', function () { alert('callback'); });
```